# Why couldn't OpenCV 3 read the video frames although OpenCV 4 could read?

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing, video-capture

I have a problem about video reading in `Python OpenCV`. Although I searched it, I could not find the reason.

I have a bunch of videos that I need to get the frames to process them. It worked for almost all videos. However, I got errors in only four videos. When I tried to run my code with OpenCV 3.4.2 the `VideoCapture.read()` returned `False` (`ret` in the below code), although `video_stream.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)` line returned the FPS without problem. However, when I tried the same code with the same four videos using OpenCV 4.2.0, it returned `True` and was able to read the frames. Here is my code which is a simple video reading code:

```
video_stream = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
fps = video_stream.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
ret, frame = video_stream.read()
```

The videos were recorded by the same device. The video codec is `H.264` for all of them and the resolutions are also the same; `1920 x 1080`.

Comment: noone cares about 3.4.2 or even 4.2.0 anymore. try to avoid such outdated versions

Comment: You are mentioning about 2 different type of versions of opencv. These versions are installed in difference computers ? This problem seems related about video/IO backend. I believe you are trying 3.4.2 version opencv in a different computer

Comment: Both are installed in the same computer in the different virtual environment.

Comment: okey, my second question is what is the output of `video_stream.isOpened()` ?

Comment: The output is True.

Comment: okey here is my last idea and suggestion: I believe that while one of your VE has a codec library, the other one doesnt have. Maybe you can check which library is lack of. Or you can try these: `sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev`

Comment: The strange part is that the one that has the problem was able to process other videos without problem as I mentioned. Therefore, I expected that it should have processed those four videos as well. If there is a missing library, shouldn't it affect all other videos too?

Comment: but you said there are in different virtual environments, that is the point

Comment: I have 100 videos that were recorded with the same device. When I used virtual environment A (has OpenCV 4.2.0), I could process all videos. But when I used virtual environment B (has OpenCV 3.4.2), I could process 96 videos but I could not process 4 of them. Therefore, I thought that if the problem is about the missing library, wouldn't I process the rest 96 videos too?